# SpaCy, Parsing, Tagging - Output as List

Tags: python, spacy

I am using spacy for nlp and I have issue printing/outputing results in a concise form. At the moment every output from (token.pos_) goes to a new line.

I was hoping to get it to print, as a list. I can do this in nltk/stanford pos, but spacy's documentation is very obfuscated. I cant seem to find out how the tokens work or how to call the values I need as in an acceptable manner. Spacy, is so mechanical.

This is my code:

```
for token in words:
    print(token.pos_)

Adj
Adj
Noun
Noun

[adj,adj]
[noun,noun]
```

I have tried

```
for token in words:
    v,x = token.pos_
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of printing, one could add the results to a list, e.g.

```
listOfPos = []

for token in words:
    listOfPos.append(token.pos_)

print listOfPos
```